# Shannon: randomness + time cannot create information?

Tags: information-theory

Does Shannon's theorem - or someone's subsequent work - state something like

> randomness + time cannot create information

Meaning: if you flip a 50/50 coin and assign heads to binary 1/tails to binary 0, you will never, ever recreate the blueprints for an airplane.

I thought it did but I cannot find any sources.

Comment: Perhaps you’re thinking of the infinite monkey theorem? (Roughly: An idealized random production of letters or strings almost surely produces e.g. the works of Shakespeare if you let it run forever)

Comment: @NapD.Lover Maybe that’s the correct one but for years now I BELIEVED I was thinking about some Shannon application.